# How can I connect aurora serverless database to HeidiSql?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, migration, aws-dms

I'm testing AWS Database Migration Service. The source database is Mysql DB, and I want to migrate to Aurora Serverless. I'm trying this in same VPC and it was successful. 
Here are the questions..
1. How can I see the Aurora Serverless Schema in Heidisql ?
Is the hostname/ip is the replication instance's public IP or original EC2 instance?
I used the Replication instance's IP, Aurora Serverless DB's user and password in Heidisql's session manager, but it occured error.
==> Can't connect to Mysql Server on 'IP'(10061)

Answer (score 1):

You can using ssh via EC2 in VPC to connect by HeidiSQL from local windows to Aurora Serveless DB.
Note at HeidiSQL tool (Settings):

- Hostname/IP: Endpoint of AWS Aurora
- User / Password / Port: All params you have created DB
  And at HeidiSQL tool (SSH tunnel): Using ssh host + port of EC2 instance.